# Unifying sources not possible due to missing fields in onCreateNode

Tags: gatsby

I'd like to unify existing sources to one single source. Think of turning all Ghost posts and Markdown files into a single node with unified fields.

My current approach is to hook into the `onCreateNode` API and create a new node for every proper node (e.g. Ghost or Markdown).

The current issue I'm facing is that Markdown nodes do not provide the proper `html` field at this point. According to the implementation these fields are added within the `setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType` API.

So my question is:

Is `onCreateNode` even the proper place to combine nodes into a single node?
If yes:  What about fields which do not exist at this point?

If no: where else?

Thanks.

Comment: Hhhhm, not simple, but I imagine you can use `createResolvers` & manually map your node type to a field of markdownRemark? You won't need to use `onCreateNode` at all

Answer (score 0):

> Is onCreateNode even the proper place to combine nodes into a single node?

It depends on the kind of fields you want to access in the process of combining. As you have noticed, if the field is defined using `setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType` and has `resolve` function which provides its value, the value is supposed to be accessible from graphql queries only, the value is provided on demand and is not present at the time `onCreateNode` is called.

It's possible to create your own fields with `setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType`, the API provides enough information to find type definition, find field definition and chain call its resolver from your resolver. Not sure if it's officially supported use of API or a hack that just happens to work:

```
exports.setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType = (
    {
        type,
        getNode
    },
        pluginOptions
) => {
    if (type.name !== 'YourNodeType') {
        return {}
    }

    return  {
        yourCombindedField: {
            type: 'String',
            resolve(node, args, context, info) {

                const parentNode = getNode(node.parent)
                const parentType = info.schema.getType(parentNode.internal.type)

                if (parentType.name === 'MarkdownRemark') {
                    const htmlField = parentType.getFields()['html']
                    return Promise.resolve(
                        const htmlInfo = {...info, fieldName: 'html', returnType: htmlField.type}
                        // call markdown html field resolve()
                        htmlField.resolve(parentNode, {}, context, htmlInfo)
                    ).then(html => {
                        return html // return combined field here
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link to gatsby [source code](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/src/redux/prepare-nodes.js#L26) which calls field resolvers, and [outdated documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-sift/#3-resolve-inner-query-fields-on-all-nodes)